# How to find element (link) on website based on either attribute or link text (javscript with jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Essentially I am trying to find this element:

`<li><a data-value="320">320 kbps</a></li>`

on a website (not my website and code is injected by chrome extension) so that I can click it, and I haven't managed yet.

I have tried this:

`$("li:contains('320 kbps')").click();`

and this:

`$('a[data-value="320"]').click();`

but neither work. I am sure that this is quite simple yet for some reason, I can't find much on this online. Thank you for help!

Comment: Your objective is to click the link on a website...your website? Someone else's website? Where exactly is your code? On a page on a website? On a page locally on your computer? In the console?

Comment: This has been solved now, however I think that I’ve made it clear in the title and summary that the link is on a website and that it’s not mine.

Comment: Nope it wasn't clear at all and I've read and answered a lot of questions. Looking at the comments of accepted answer shows that you had to go back and forth to resolve your issue so yeah not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one should be `$("li a:contains('320 kbps')")` or else you get all the listitems that contain `320 kbps`

The second one should work as is. For example:

```
let a = $('a[data-value="320"]');
```

```js
let a = $('a[data-value="320"]');
console.log(a.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a data-value="320">320 kbps</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then for example add a clickhandler:

```js
$('a[data-value="320"]').bind("click", function() {
  console.log("clicked!");
});
$('a[data-value="320"]').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a data-value="320">320 kbps</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is very weird as I tried your code and it does indeed find the element yet clicking on the link doesn't produce any results on the website. Although when I click the link myself I get the `clicked` output in the console and the website responds.

Comment: Are you sure the html is there? What if you open the website and run the code in the console? Does that give the expected result?

Comment: I got the output for `console.log(a.html());` of `320 kbps` so that works but then the click didn't work: `VM113:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: I have updated the examples, right now they should all work.

Comment: I hate to bother you again but whilst `$('a[data-value="320"]').click();` is now working in the console, when I run it in my javascript file the website still isn't reacting despite no errors whatsoever and the message `clicked` in the console.

Comment: I have realised that the code works as long as I press the link myself once. After this the script actually presses the button. Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Nevermind it is actually that the website adds `class="active"` to the link whereas there was no class before and when the link is clicked again the class is not removed but set to `""` therefore my solution is to give the link a class before I click it. Anyhow your solution is correct without this context so I will keep it this way. Have a good day/night!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("a[data-value=320]").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a data-value="320" onclick="alert('clicked');">320 kbps</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[data-value="320"]` in your selector:

```js
$('li > a[data-value="320"]').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a data-value="320">320 kbps</a></li>
```